# asp.net installer simple

Tags: asp.net, iis, installation

I have an asp.net 2.0 application.  I would like to package it into an installer.  For clarification, on the user's machine there is already a "VFP application" installed.  Here are the requirements:

-Check for the presence of iis and install whatever version is available to that machines operating system

-Check for the presence of asp.net and install (or activate) if necessary

-Create the iis application and sub folders on target machine

-Modify the application pool to provide for 32 bit applications

-Check for and install if not present Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0

-Determine the location of an existing "VFP application" and copy several additional files to that "VFP application" location

-Mark the "VFP application" folder as read/write for the iis app pool user

I'm looking for an installer which could perform the above with a minimal learning curve and hopefully low cost or open source.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As a free solution WiX is the best, as mentioned by Darth above. However, if you are willing to spend a small amount, you can get the Professional edition of [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). This is GUI based, so the speed of implementation is much bigger. Also passing the project to another colleague will be much simpler since working with Advanced Installer is quite easy to learn.

The [following IIS tutorial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html) can help you get started. You can try it for free, with the 30 days trial.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try using [**WiX**](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application) outlines the process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did mention "minimal learning curve", but maybe I'm being too picky.  InstallShield LE 2012 for VS2012 is close, but there are some of my requirements I can't figure out how to do - but then again, possibly I just don't know what I'm doing!